# Sources for Alexandrov surfaces

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, metric-spaces

There are two distinct notions in differential geometry associated
with A. D. Alexandrov: (1) Alexandrov *spaces* of courvature bounded
from below; (2) Alexandrov *surfaces* of bounded total curvature (more precisely integral of absolute value of Gaussian curvature is bounded).

(The confusion is reflected in our tag [alexandrov-geometry](/questions/tagged/alexandrov-geometry).) Here
(1) was extensively studied in particular by Burago, Gromov, and
Perelman.

This question concerns the notion (2).  These *surfaces* were
extensively studied by Reshetnyak e.g.,

Reshetnyak, Yu. G.  On the conformal representation of Alexandrov
surfaces.  Papers on analysis, 287-304, Rep. Univ. Jyväskylä
Dep. Math. Stat., 83, Univ. Jyväskylä, Jyväskylä, 2001.

There is a nice survey article by Troyanov:

Marc Troyanov, Les surfaces à courbure intégrale bornée au sens
d'Alexandrov.  https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.3407

However, I haven't found anything like a complehensive or definitive
treatment of these *surfaces*, and am therefore looking for such a
reference.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand your question. , "I haven't found anything like a complehensive or definitive treatment of these surfaces,"

Comment: When I was master student I read some papers about Ricci flow on such surfaces

Comment: @HassanJolany, I would have expected to find a book treating this topic, or at least a detailed article with all the background.  Troyanov's article is very nice but it skips over most of the details.

Comment: have a look http://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/papers/akp-papers/shiohama_1.pdf

Comment: @HassanJolany, your comment is a good illustration of the confusion I mentioned in my *question*.  Shiohama's paper on Petrunin's site is about (1), not about (2).

Comment: What about the monograph: Aleksandrov, A. D.; Zalgaller, V. A.; "Intrinsic geometry of surfaces", 1967. I think it treats surfaces of type (2)  Do you consider it to be out of date?

Comment: @salev, I haven't looked at it yet but given the number of articles Reshetnyak wrote on this since, there is a good chance it is incomplete.  Are you familiar with the Alexandrov-Zalgaller text?

Comment: @MikhailKatz: I have had a very brief glance long ago. I do not know this theory. I am wondering if there is a multi-dimensional version of it by now.

Answer (score 7):

The most comprehensive is probably the survey of Reshetnyak (a yellow Encyclopedia book):

Reshetnyak, Two-dimensional Manifolds of Bounded Curvature, Encyclopaedia of Math. Sci., Vol. 70, Geometry IV, Springer, 1993.

Among people who worked on this recently are Thomas Richard and Clement Debin, see e.g. Clement's article [A compactness theorem for surfaces with Bounded Integral Curvature](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.07755).

Answer (score 7):

I agree with the answer by Ivan Izmestiev, but let me add the original monograph
by Alexandrov and Zalgaller,

Intrinsic geometry of surfaces, English translation,
American Mathematical Society, Providence, R.I. 1967.

It is a different treatment of the subject in comparison with Reshetnyak, and it is also quite comprehensive.
Instead of potential theory of Reshetnyak, their main method is elementary geometry. Of the recent applications of this theory let me mention two
papers by M. Bonk:

MR2006006 
Bonk, Mario; Lang, Urs
Bi-Lipschitz parameterization of surfaces, 
Math. Ann. 327 (2003), no. 1, 135–169, and

MR1804531 Bonk, M.; Eremenko, A. Covering properties of meromorphic functions, negative curvature and spherical geometry. Ann. of Math. (2) 152 (2000), no. 2, 551–592.